# MonetDB client compilation

Tags: c, database, monetdb

I'm a beginner in the Database community. I have been trying to interface with MonetDB using C/C++ [MAPI](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/Programming/MAPI). I have installed MonetDB on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine and when I try to compile a sample program from [here](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/Programming/MAPI), I get the following error:

```
$ gcc test.c -I /usr/include/monetdb -lmapi
```

> test.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `mapi_explain_query'
>   test.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to`mapi_result_error'
>   test.c:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `mapi_explain_result'
>   test.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to`mapi_next_result'
>   test.c:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `mapi_close_handle'
>   test.c:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to`mapi_destroy'
>   test.c:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `mapi_explain'
>   test.c:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to`mapi_destroy'
>   /tmp/cctyQopc.o: In function `query':
>   test.c:(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to`mapi_query'
>   test.c:(.text+0x110): undefined reference to `mapi_error'
>   /tmp/cctyQopc.o: In function`update':
>   test.c:(.text+0x160): undefined reference to `mapi_close_handle'
>   /tmp/cctyQopc.o: In function`main':
>   test.c:(.text+0x1b6): undefined reference to `mapi_connect'
>   test.c:(.text+0x1c6): undefined reference to`mapi_error'
>   test.c:(.text+0x238): undefined reference to `mapi_fetch_field'
>   test.c:(.text+0x24d): undefined reference to`mapi_fetch_field'
>   test.c:(.text+0x277): undefined reference to `mapi_fetch_row'
>   test.c:(.text+0x287): undefined reference to`mapi_close_handle'
>   test.c:(.text+0x293): undefined reference to `mapi_destroy'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

This question has previously been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087473/monetdb-test-client-application-not-linking/35321216#35321216) and the answer did not solve the problem (although the answer was accepted, I'm not sure why). Any help/directions would be great!

Comment: These are link errors. You need to specify the library info with the -L option.  The -I option is to tell the compiler where the include header files are located.

Comment: @bruceg I have the -L option in place already. Sorry that it was not part of the original post. I have edited it now

Comment: I don't see the `-L` option, just the `-l` one. But I don't think you need, if you installed the MonetDB library with your package manager.

Comment: Can you try `pkg-config --libs monetdb-mapi` and `pkg-config --cflags monetdb-mapi`?

Comment: @9769953 works perfectly fine now! The commands you pointed out helped me figure out some of the missing packages. After installing them, and after following the steps to compile and link as shown here (https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/Programming/MAPI), it works now! Thank you.

Comment: Could you self-answer your question by what exactly you did now? E.g., what flags did you pass to the compiler? What were the results of above commands?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04 using:

pkg-config --libs monetdb-mapi and pkg-config --cflags monetdb-mapi

Won't work because Ubuntu doesn't have a bzip2.pc:

Here how it worked:

gcc main.c -I /usr/include/monetdb -lmapi -lssl -lcrypto -lstream -lcurl -llzma -lbz2