# Linking error using C code to connect to Monetdb

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors, mapi, monetdb

I have tried to compile the code shown [here](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/Programming/MAPI):

But I got a linking error.
I tried the solution mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087473/monetdb-test-client-application-not-linking).

But again, I got this error:

> gcc main.c -I /usr/include/monetdb -lmapi
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `SHA224_Update'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`mnstr_settimeout'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `socket_rastream'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`mnstr_destroy'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `SHA384_Init'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`MD5_Final'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `RIPEMD160_Init'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`mnstr_errnr'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `RIPEMD160_Update'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`SHA384_Update'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `SHA224_Init'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`SHA256_Init'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `SHA512_Update'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`mnstr_init'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `block_stream'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`mnstr_write'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `SHA384_Final'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`SHA1_Update'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `mnstr_error'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`SHA512_Final'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `SHA256_Final'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`mnstr_flush'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `SHA1_Init'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`SHA224_Final'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `mnstr_read_block'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`mnstr_printf'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `SHA256_Update'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`isa_block_stream'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `mnstr_set_byteorder'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`mnstr_read'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `socket_wastream'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`MD5_Init'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `RIPEMD160_Final'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`close_stream'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`SHA1_Final'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to `open_wastream'
>
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libmapi.so: undefined reference to`SHA512_Init'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

When I tried the solution mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51644081/monetdb-client-compilation):

```
pkg-config --libs monetdb-mapi and pkg-config --cflags monetdb-mapi
```

I got this error:

> The package `bzip2` was not found in the `pkg-config` search path.
>   Perhaps you should add the directory containing `bzip2.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable.
>   Package 'bzip2', required by 'monetdb-stream', not found

which, after a search, I found, that Debian doesn't have a `bzip2.pc`.
I have installed the following libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libmonetdb-client-dev
sudo apt-get install libmonetdb-stream-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev
```

So any help would be appreciated.
My Ubuntu version is 18.04

Comment: It looks like you are missing linking with libSSL (e.g. `-lssl`, and possibly `-lcrypto`) look at what is not found, e.g. "undefined reference to `SHA224_Update`". See [SHA224_Update](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SHA224_Update.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to what @David C. Rankin mentioned the linking problem vanished:
Here is the full command:

gcc main.c -I /usr/include/monetdb -lmapi -lssl -lcrypto -lstream -lcurl -llzma -lbz2